# Understanding rails polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to understand how to use polymorphic associations in RoR, any help would be greatly appreciated - I’ve read a couple of articles and I’m still really confused on how to create the models below.

Basically I would like to have a class called DrumUsage it will have multiple Added_Usages and multiple Removed_Usages.

## Here is a diagram to show what I would like it to look like .

[image]

Comment: It doesn't look like your use case requires polymorphic associations.

Comment: are `added_usage_id` and `removed_usage_id` ever used at the same time?

Comment: yes because DrumUsage will have both an added_usage and a removed usage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if I were you, I would have a `Drum`, something like:

```
class Drum < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :drum_usages

end
```

And then a `DrumUsage` (I don't love the name, but I guess it works) something like:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: drum_usages
#
#  id              :bigint           not null, primary key
#  note            :text
#  drum_id         :integer
#  person_id       :integer
#  usage_type      :integer          not null
#  fluid_amount    :float            not null
#  created_at      :datetime         not null
#  updated_at      :datetime         not null
#
class DrumUsage < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :drum

  enum usage_type: {added: 0, removed: 1}

end
```

I guessed on that `fluid_amount` bit. I don't know if that's a number, and if so what kind of number. So, I just stuck `:float` in there.

Then you could do operations on `@drum.drum_usages` to do stuff like figure out how much liquid is currently in the drum, who all the people are who added/subtracted liquid from the drum. When the last time liquid was added/removed. And so on.

Comment: I really like this approach thank you!